# Apache request contains full physical path when trailing slash omitted

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

My original goal was to rewrite requests to `http://server.com/node/XXXXX` to `http://server.com/node/index.cgi?XXXXX`. `node` really is a physical directory containing `index.cgi`, located directly under the document root. That bit is fairly straightforward:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
Options         +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /node
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.cgi
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /node/index.cgi?$1 [L,QSA]
```

...in the `.htaccess` file under `/real/path/to/web/stuff/node`.

Note that this means requests of the form `http://server.com/node/` supply an empty query string to `index.cgi`, which is what I want.

So now the tricky part: I want requests to `http://server.com/node` to redirect to `http://server.com/node/` — which, as above, redirects to `index.cgi` with an empty QS. The trouble is, if I don't have any rules in my root dir, a request for `http://server.com/node` does indeed seem to go to `http://server.com/node/` — but I find that the query string given to `index.cgi` is the full physical path corresponding to the request (`/real/path/to/web/stuff/node`)!

I've tried a rule in my **root level** `.htaccess` like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/node
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /node/ [L] # (also tried [L,R=302])
```

But that has no effect.

I realise that Apache does some trailing-slash appending under the hood, but I can't use `DirectorySlash Off`... and I wouldn't want to if I could, since I have a Drupal installation residing in the root (there are a bunch if similar rewriting rules in there, but I don't think they're interfering).

So is it possible to either create a rule for the root directory `.htaccess` that works, or a modify the `/node/.htaccess` to make it not matter? Even physically moving things around is not beyond reason.

This is on a host running Apache 1.3.41 on FreeBSD 7.3. I don't have the ability to change anything about the server config itself, only my `.htaccess` files (which means I can't even turn on rewrite logging!).

Answer (score 1):

The Apache 1.3 documentation has an [entry referring to the "trailing slash problem"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/misc/rewriteguide.html), maybe it may help you for that scenario.

Regarding your rules with the node IDs, the RewriteBase maybe your problem since "the local directory prefix is stripped .. and your rewriting rules act only on the remainder" as documented in [the RewriteBase docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteBase).

Comment: Removing the `RewriteBase` didn't have any effect. I still get the full local path as the URL.